# Weird Windows 10 Search

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I installed Intel Rapid Storage but after restarting, my laptop wouldn't stop shutting down by itself. So I went to safe mode and deleted the setup folder in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Intel\Setup$`

It didn't work.  I uninstalled the Intel RS and then my windows worked and stopped shutting down. But now, after I begin searching with the windows search, it shows this:

[image: Here]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to check your system files for damage. This can be done from an elevated (admin) command prompt. Simply type `sfc /scannow` and let the scan run. It should attempt to repair any damaged files found, and may fix this issue. The first link describes this option further.

Another option to consider would be restore points. Sometimes, restore points are automatically created, and can undo harmful changes, including to the registry. This may be an option you want to try last, but if it's available, it should fix the issue. The second link contains a guide for restore points.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184577.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/